# Acquiring TextView from ListView using ID

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview and each listitem contains a textview with the following attributes.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The text stored in the textview is acquired from an external database and is different for each listItem. I try to access the text in the following way however, every single time I get '1' as the answer.

```
public void clicking(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
    TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gid);
    String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
```

How do I get the text from the listItem the user has clicked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`, and then operate like this:

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gid);
            String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

In this way it will get the text from the one and only `R.id.gid` `TextView` contained the clicked `ListItem`.

Comment: I get a "non static method setOnItemClickListener cannot be referenced from within static context